# Using Azure Key Vault from a Mac

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-keyvault

I am trying to read/write secrets from Azure Key Vault, in a C# Console App. You can see the code below, but I basically just followed the [Microsoft Quick Start Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net?tabs=azure-cli). I have used this before, successfully, on a Windows Machine. But when I do it on my MacBook (M1), I just get an error:

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
- Operating system Darwin 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Wed Aug 10 14:28:35 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.141.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 isn't supported.
- Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot
- Azure CLI not installed
- PowerShell is not installed.
```

I see that it's complaining about a lot of missing stuff, but how do I fix that? I have installed the AZ CLI Tool and I have run `az login` in the terminal (and verified that it works). I have even managed to list my key vaults, with the CLI Tool, so it's not that there is no connection.

**Update:** It turns out that I only get this error when running in VS Code. When I switch to Visual Studio, it seems to work.

Minimum code example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Attempting to read from Key Vault...");

string keyVaultName = "<key-vault-name>";

var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

string secretName = "<secret-name>";
var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

Console.WriteLine(secret.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could be able to make this work without any errors but could able to reproduce the same error when I logged out using `az logout` in Azure CLI. So, the reason you are receiving this is because Visual Studio somehow dropped its Azure Authentication connection. When I logged in to Azure using `az login` once again from Azure CLI I could able to run without any errors. I am using the same code that you have provided.

> Console.WriteLine("Attempting to read from Key Vault...");
>
> string keyVaultName = "";
>
> var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net"; var client
> = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
>
> string secretName = ""; var secret = await
> client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
>
> Console.WriteLine(secret.Value.ToString());

***Results when logged out***

[image]

***Results when logged in using az login***

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should try with Visual Studio instead. Currently I'm using VS Code. I just didn't think that would make any difference...

Comment: Interestingly it actually works when run from Visual Studio. The question is why? And how to get it to work in VS Code then.

Comment: I think this has to do with the version of the `Azure.Identity` nuget package that is being used. If you try to add an explicitly reference to the v1.6 version (or greater) of that package, does it work for you? (some pkgs will bring a dependency on older version of it from 2020, v1.3, which didn't seem to be supported on VS for Mac at the time that version was published.